# Is it possible to have more Loggers in ServiceStack for the same AppHost?

Tags: servicestack, nlog

I'm creating a Plugin for ServiceStack that contains certain services. However, I want these services to Log to another DB (in my case) that the other services in the AppHost.

Is it possible to register 2 ILog interfaces inside the AppHost?

The `ServiceStack.Logging.LogManager.GetLogger(GetType())` will always return an ILog interface. Do I need to create a second ILog implementation for the other Logger?

I'm using NLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ServiceStack, so my suggestion might not make sense (but it does make sense when considering NLog in isolation).

Can't you just configure another Target in the NLog.config file and configure your loggers to write to that Target?

For example...

Configure some targets in the NLog.config (I am configuring a console target and a file target)

```
  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${message}" fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}.log" />
    <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} | ${message}" />
  </targets>
```

Configure some rules

```
<rules>
  <logger name="Your.Name.Space1.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" /> 
  <logger name="Your.Name.Space2.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" /> 
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="console" /> 
</rules>
```

Now, all classes from Your.Name.Space1 and Your.Name.Space2 will log to the "file" target while all other classes will log to the "console" target.  You could add `"final=true"` to the loggers for your classes if you want their logs to appear only in the "file" target.

I think that should all you to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @wageoghe for this suggestion. In my case this would be possible because the ServiceStack Plugin is a separate class library and indeed has a namespace that is different. So this could work indeed!